# How to disable Web Console and Red Hat Insights prompt on login to RHEL8 via SSH?

Tags: ssh, redhat, rhel8, motd

Whenever I log into my RHEL8 server via SSH, I get these lines printed:

```
Web console: https://<myserver>:9090/ or https://<myip>:9090/

This system is not registered to Red Hat Insights. See https://cloud.redhat.com/
To register this system, run: insights-client --register
```

How do I disable those prompts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out before I finished writing this question so I figured I'd just share this with anyone else.

```
# ls /etc/motd.d -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Mar 12 19:46 cockpit -> /run/cockpit/motd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 41 Jun 18 22:01 insights-client -> /etc/insights-client/insights-client.motd
```

Each one of those symlinks prints something to the SSH terminal on login. In this case, `cockpit` prints the web console message and `insights-client` prints the insights prompt.

Therefore just do this:

```
# cd /etc/motd.d
# [sudo] rm -f cockpit insights-client
```

Verified to work and persist across restart on `RHEL8.4`.